# Return value curve_fit

Tags: python

Supposing that I have a function such as:

```
def Gaussian(x,I,sigma):
    return I/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma))*np.exp(-x*x/(2*sigma*sigma))
```

If I use:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gaussian, xVal, yVal)
```

and then I print popt and pcov, I obtain respectively

```
 popt= [2.47388884 1.09054634]
 pcov= [[ 2.31740586e-04 -3.06314407e-06]
       [-3.06314407e-06  1.04053180e-04]]
```

Could someone explain me what curve_fit of scipy.optimize returns? Reading online I've understand that pcov is the covariance matrix, but it's not to much clear what are the values of popt, with reference to the posted function.
Thanks!

Comment: I = 2.47388884, sigma = 1.09054634

Comment: ok, so they are the vaule of the parameters that I have in my function! Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Those are optimal values for the parameters of your `Gaussian` function.